# Doesn't have master script ASP.NET website on sharepoint

Tags: asp.net

I really don't know how to ask about this, it's not about scripting or troubleshoot in ASP.NET but this question it's very important for me, so I need some suggestion's.

I was bought a ASP.NET website, and short stories the Developer installing to my server directly through/into Sharepoint (He suggested me to buy too .-the Sharepoint). After several months I need to change some menu and content's and I'm hiring my college friend and he was confused because there are no script at all inside the Sharepoint and the he was checked the wwwroot folder and there's nothing in it only couples regular setting/configuration files.

Then he told me that my site was running only using the configuration in Sharepoint, I really didn't understand what that meant. My friend explained that he cannot changed anything without the original scripts, because my site only runs by configuration.

So I told him that I was paying for a site not a configuration, I understand little bit, I should also have the script not just a configuration, and directly I was contacting the first Developer and asked for the scripts and he said that I have to pay for the scripts and the price he asked was even more expensive than the first price when he was offering at the first time.

Right know I totally confused, because my friend said that me and him can't do anything without the scripts and he said that if the configuration lost or deleted accidentally the worst case is broken I will lost everything (my site).

Somebody can give me a clue or suggestion what I have suppose to do?

Answer (score 0):

Something here doesn't make much sense.

You have a server where a hired SharePoint developer installed SharePoint for you on this server and set it up using some scripts (most likely PowerShell).

SharePoint is so much more than just an ASP.NET website. The reason why your friend (I'm assuming he doesn't know SharePoint) can't find anything at `\wwwroot` is because SharePoint only stores its web.config file in that directory. Everything else (which you should not fiddle with without proper knowledge) is stored somewhere else on the server.

What you want to change, you don't need the scripts for. The scripts are primarily only for configuring SharePoint on a level higher than changing menus and content.

If you want to change the Navigation menu and write some new text on your website; you can achieve this through the user interface of SharePoint.

You should have a set of credentials so you can login on your SharePoint site and be able to change texts etc.
I suggest you go to a SharePoint workshop for end users where you learn how to properly use SharePoint and it's many features.

Comment: I meant exactly is we need the website script/website source code. The developer was a Programmer I think, not a Share Point developer he just want to sell the license he had I guessed.The Programmer said that there are no source code because my website runs using configuration in SharePoint. Well I thought S.P was like a localhost or something to run ASP.NET website. Apparently the Programmer now kept the source code and I don't know how SharePoint can run my website only with using configuration, what I've red ASP usually put the source code inside the /wwwroot.